# How to get the 1st column for all rows within a table using Selenium java API

Tags: xpath, selenium

I got a table with `<tr>` data as:

```
<tr class="iceDatTblRow1" id="body-subview:myMainPage:MainTabs:0:dataTable:0">
 <td class="iceDatTblCol1"><span class="iceOutTxt" id="body-
   subview:myMainPage:MainTabs:0:dataTable:0:j_idt252">Data that I want</span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

for some reason, i can't seem to locate the `<td>` with `id` attribute within it...
please share your expertise - thanks,

Comment: Can you show the **XPath** that you have been testing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about **Selenium** but there are many **XPath** solutions here. A few examples:

- `span` everywhere:

```
//span[@id='body-subview:myMainPage:MainTabs:0:dataTable:0:j_idt252']
```

- `span` only inside `td`:

```
//td/span[@id='body-subview:myMainPage:MainTabs:0:dataTable:0:j_idt252']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get all the first column for all rows with Selenium and Xpath then you can try this code:

```
String tdLocator="//tr"
int count = selenium.getXpathCount(tdLocator)
for(int i = 1;i<=count;i++)
{
get to td by using //tr[i]/td[0]
}
```

If you have a table ID then you can also use

```
selenium.getTable("table_id.[rownumber].[colnumber])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...the 2nd solution seems to work - now I can loop through...